# Is it possible to use a Multimeter for detecting electric leads?

Tags: multimeter, wire, detection

Is it possible to DIY my multimeter into a detector for active wires (charge flowing at that very moment) inside a wall?

I don't know, maybe something with a coil or metal plates?

The application would be localizing a wire in a wall so I know where not to drill into.

Comment: if it has an accurate current meter that can go down into the micro-amp range, you can use a current transformer to make a contactless current meter. Commercially these are available as 'clamp current meters'

Comment: I think my question was not properly explaining my use case. I'd like to detect a wire in a wall. Doesn't have to be super accurate.

Comment: Detecting a wire in a wall is best done using a metal detector.

Comment: Yes. However the meter would just act as an indicator for a detector circuit that you would need to design. The circuit would probably need to be separately powered, but it is possible that you could design a circuit to be powered by the ohmmeter function of the meter.

Comment: Okay, I didn't expect it to be that complicated. I thought that an active wire will just either induce a current or resistance in another wire hooked up with the multimeter by means of its magnetic field. And then I'd try to detect a maximum of the respective metric by hovering it over the wall. I just need to know whether the wire terminating at an outlet is coming from top/bottom/left/right.

Comment: In the USA, I would shut off the power to the outlet, open it, and look in with a flashlight or pull the outlet out of the box. Is something like that not possible where you are? I don't think anything really simple will give you a signal that is sufficient to detect with a multimeter.

Comment: Can you tell us if you'll be drilling into a stud or into the space between studs in a wall? You can't rely on code to keep you safe but any wire passing through studs is *supposed* to be protected from accidental drilling by a steel plate. Wires running vertically in pockets between studs should be loose enough that you're more likely to just push them out of the way with a drill bit than to actually pierce/damage the insulation.

Comment: The short answer is no a multimeter cannot detect a cable inside a wall.  Some "stud detectors" will detect a cable inside a wall (some don't).. A tool called a cable tracer will definitely detect a cable in a wall (or buried up to 300mm in the ground), however you need to plug in a transmitter to a power point first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to reliably detect any current flow through the drywall/sheeting on your wall without using some active components. One of the comments suggested a metal detector which is basically what you're creating with some wire loops, a transistor and a power supply. Check out this $10 diy metal detector kit to get the basic idea:
[Elenco Soldering Metal Detector Kit](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0019SMDK2)

There are cheap passive non-contact detectors that'll work if you hold them up right in front of an active power outlet but that wouldn't work through a wall.